# How to use remote file source module

Tags: 7, files

I would like to use the [Remote File Source](https://www.drupal.org/project/remote_file_source) Module.

But I could not find any documentation related to it.

Has anyone succeeded using it?

How to provide ftp hyper link inside a blog, article, forum.

I would like to insert a node url inside CKEditor. The node must be a custom node which will fetch a file from an FTP url some think like a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your content type and click edit on your file field in question.

- Click on File Sources.
- ☑ Remote File.

[image]

Comment: please provide the location of the admin/.../.../ path to go to this screen, can we really use a file which is not uploaded inside the drupal files?

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire you just need to edit your file field, [I am using image as an example here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VmHUh.jpg)

Comment: can we use an FTP URL from which the Drupal will directly fetch and display on the fly without storing locally?